# Returning a promise value in Angular 2, Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, ionic2

I am familiarizing myself with Angular2, Ionic2 and
maybe I am misunderstanding something but was hoping for assistance.

I have a provider called 'CurrentUser' for the purpose of storing and getting LocalStorage data.

```
     getProfile(): any {
      this.local.get("user-profile").then((profile) => {
      var val = JSON.parse(profile);
      return val;
  });
}
```

this function `getProfile()` returns a promise

If I inject this provider into a component. How would I await the promise to to resolve before assigning the data when calling this function from the component?.

```
@Component({
   templateUrl: 'build/pages/book_meeting/book_meeting.html'
})
 export class BookMeetingPage implements OnInit {
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private _currentUser: CurrentUser) {
}

profile: IProfile;

   ngOnInit(): any {
   this.profile = this._currentUser.getProfile();
   console.log(this.profile);//returns undefined
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all you have to return `this.local.get("user-profile")` promise from `getProfile` function so that it can chain when you call. Thereafter you can get data returned from `getProfile` function in `.then` success callback.

```
getProfile(): any {
   return this.local.get("user-profile").then((profile) => {
      var val = JSON.parse(profile);
      return val;
   });
);
```

Additionally you can't get data as soon as you make an ajax, on success of it you can get the response

```
ngOnInit(): any {
   this._currentUser.getProfile().then(
     value => { console.log(value) }
   )
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I get the error app.bundle.js:44529 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.

Comment: @Arianule sorry I mentioned in answer, but forgot to change the same thing in code part, my bad. Thanks for heads up. Check updated code

Comment: Hi there Pankaj. Did you update the code, sorry. should i return a Promise...something along the lines of return Promise.resolve(val) ?

Comment: @Arianule I changed here `this.local.get("user-profile")` to `return this.local.get("user-profile")`

Comment: Aaaah, apologies, now I see. Sorry...been a long day :-)

Comment: @Arianule np, that happens, Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Your function getProfile doesn't return a promise. It returns nothing.
You should change it to

```
 getProfile(): any {
  return this.local.get("user-profile").then((profile) => {
  var val = JSON.parse(profile);
  return val;
 });
```

Now in your component, you can extract the data from your profile promise variable.

```
   ngOnInit(): any {
   this._currentUser.getProfile().then(value => {
        console.log(value); //returns your value.
  }
```